# How to set opacity when drawing on surfaceview

Tags: android, canvas

I am getting same error as mentioned in below link.

[Setting the opacity of drawing canvas in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28271015/setting-the-opacity-of-drawing-canvas-in-android)

But i could not understand how to solve this. 
please help me.

Answer (score 0):

I think we can not set opacity in surfaceview (In terms of no effect will be visible of opacity). If you want to do that use TextureView instead of surfaceview.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is simple: draw the lines on a different Bitmap (that stay only in memory) USING FULL OPACITY and then draw this new Bitmap (using "drawBitmap()") over the normal one applying the Alpha you want.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is

```
SurfaceView#setAlpha
```

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/SurfaceView#setAlpha(float)